# Asterisk PBX - Transfer nuisance calls to special extension

Tags: voip

I'm using asterisk 1.8.14 and freepbx 2.10.

I keep getting telemarketing calls and want to do the following when they call.

1. Have a special extension number I can manually transfer the calls to
2. The special extension should auto answer and start playing the pre-recorded message. I also want to record the extension.

Secondly I want to be able to have a blacklist of numbers which will be automatically forwarded to the special extension

Answer (score 0):

I dug around in the cookbook sections on voip-info.org and found this link http://www.jackenhack.com/adding-blacklist-to-an-asteriskhome-pbx-voip-server/ which appears to be what you are asking. It's a simple blacklist that can be implemented directly in the dialplan.

http://www.jackenhack.com/adding-blacklist-to-an-asteriskhome-pbx-voip-server/

Mostly for your amusement, but also because I hate telemarketers, I'll point out there's the example of a "telemarketer torture" IVR that was used in the past to illustrate how Asterisk's IVR works, for which you should still be able to find all the prompt messages recorded. http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Telemarketer+Torture